# How to Best do End to End TLS in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am looking to see some feasible solution and recommendation on how people are doing it.
My Setup is :
AWS EKS Cluster Running a App as deployment. This is public facing cluster , that has the service configured to use "LoadBalancer" that created NLB , Below is my service configuration. This is all basic and it's working fine.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: instance
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-service
  namespace: default-namespace
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.10.20.135
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.10.20.135
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 14.56.361.259/32
  - 172.201.416.179/32
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30294
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: my-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Requirement now is to use a domain instead of a load balancer and ensure that Its going to do End to End TLS till pod. I am trying to find the best way and steps. I have AWS Load Balancer Controller and Cert-Manager in the cluster already.

My though is if I have a domain that somehow can be configured to route traffic to NLB in route53 and then NLB keeping the TLS end to end send the traffic to Pod , would that work ? Or should I take the route of change the service to use "NodePort" and Create Ingress that creates a new ALB and then use ACM cert and that route to pod and then pod does TLS termination as I have to make sure the pod make use of certificates.

Thanks for help and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

using below annotation we can give acm arn to service NLB

service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert

> 

My though is if I have a domain that somehow can be configured to route traffic to NLB in route53 and then NLB keeping the TLS end to end send the traffic to Pod , would that work —- yes this will work.

Thanks.

Comment: That's for the cert but How do I map a domain without Ingress setup using the existing NLB.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).